# How can you check if AC_PROG_CXX has failed?

Tags: autoconf

The `AC_PROG_CXX` macro checks for possible C++ compilers and in the event of failure, happily just sets `CXX` to g++ even if it knows g++ doesn't really exist.

My question is, how can you understand if `AC_PROG_CXX` did actually find a proper compiler?

I am asking because I have a C++ library in my project that could be optionally compiled. I can't seem to figure out how on earth I'm supposed to know whether I can actually compile anything with `CXX`.

---

Some of the macros like `AC_PROG_CC_C99` give a variable (in this case `ac_cv_prog_cc_c99`) that can tell me if the feature exists or not. I tried `ac_cv_prog_cxx` and similar things, but it doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try compiling a minimal program, e.g.,

```
AC_LANG_PUSH([C++])
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
  [[#ifndef __cplusplus
    #error "broken C++"
    #endif]])],,
  [CXX=;])
AC_LANG_POP([C++])
```

If the compilation fails, we explicitly set `CXX` to an empty string. So depending on what you want to do:

```
if test "x$CXX" != x ; then
  ... we have a working C++ compiler - setup optional stuff ...
fi
```

Or as part of a [conditional](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Subdirectories-with-AM_005fCONDITIONAL) build in a `Makefile.am` file:

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLE_CXX_SRC], [test "x$CXX" != x])
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to send a patch to add a variable to `AC_PROG_CXX` itself to tell the results because it wouldn't make sense to call the compiler yet another time to be able to tell what should have already been known.